# Django spirit in create topic when generate error of Could not find config for '%s' in settings.CACHES"

Tags: python, django

[image]I integrate with django project with spirit and after spirit in create topic then generate error in  Could not find config for '%s' in settings.CACHES".

settings.py in spirit->conf->settings.py

```
 from . import defaults

__all__ = ['settings']


class Settings:
    """
    Get a setting from django settings or\
    Spirit's defaults. In that order
    """

    def __getattr__(self, item):
        try:
            return getattr(django_settings, item)
        except AttributeError:
            return getattr(defaults, item)


settings = Settings()
```

defaults.py file call in main projects settings.py by

```
from spirit.core.conf import defaults
```

Comment: Post your code please. This screencap won't help anyone in debugging your issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

main projects settings.py in put CACHES confrugations.